# Passing TempData from action filter to action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've been trying to pass TempData from ActionFilter to the action using :

```
filterContext.Controller.TempData.Add("Key","Value");
```

However, it appears that no TempData is passed to the action as I keep getting the `Object not referenced to an instance of the object` error.

Is this the right way to pass TempData to the controller from the ActionFilter ? if not, how can I do this ?

Comment: Actually your code seems to work for me. I am using MVC5. How are you applying your ActionFilter? As attribute?

Comment: @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets: Yeah, I'm using it as an attribute

Comment: Works for me. Maybe Value which you pass to temp data is itself null?

Comment: @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets: it cant be I'm passing exactly as shown in the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will work :-

**Answer 1 :**

Filter :-

```
public class MyCustomAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
  public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
  {
    filterContext.RouteData.Values.Add("Key","Value");
  }
}
```

Controller :-

```
[MyCustom]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    TempData["Key"] = RouteData.Values["Key"];

    return View();
}
```

**Answer 2 :**

Filter :-

```
public class MyCustomAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Controller.TempData.Add("Key","Value");
    }
}
```

Controller :-

```
[MyCustom]
public ViewResult Index()
{
    string Tempval = TempData["Key"].ToString();
    return View();
}
```

Comment: I'm using it inside a ` public override void OnActionExecuted`, could this be the issue

Comment: yes..try using it inside OnActionExecuting instead,,

Comment: You shouldn't use OnActionExecuted because this method is called when action is already executed (after). Try to use OnActionExecuting instead.

Comment: Answer 1 did NOT worked for me. But 2. answer did the trick very well!

Answer (score 3):

Filter code:

```
public class MyWhateverAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Controller.TempData.Add("some key", "some value");
    }
}
```

Action code:

```
[MyWhatever]
public ViewResult Index()
{
    string value = TempData["some key"] as string;
    return View();
}
```

Note: you must ensure that your filter code is executed before the action code in order to pass some value, that's why `OnActionExecuting` is the method that needs to be overridden