# webapi - Custom value Provider to capture request header

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

In ASP.NET Web-API, i am trying to read the Http request header information with the help of custom value provider technique mentioned in this article

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/fetch-header-information-using-customvalueprovider-in-asp-ne/

Now this technique is working fine and it is giving me the value for the desired header key. But i want to modify the API controller action method signature to get the entire dictionary object of header.

My API controller method is looking like this :-

```
   [HttpPost]
   [Route("user-documents")]
  public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetUserDocuments([ValueProvider(typeof(CustomHeaderProviderFactory))] string Client, SearchCriteria incomingObj)
        {    .... Logic ...... }
```

And here are the classes for the CustomHeaderProviderFactory.

```
  public class CustomHeaderProviderFactory : ValueProviderFactory
    {
        public override IValueProvider GetValueProvider(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            return new CustomHeaderValueProvider(actionContext);
        }
    }


    public class CustomHeaderValueProvider : IValueProvider
    {

        public Dictionary<string, string> objCollection;
        public CustomHeaderValueProvider(HttpActionContext context)
        {
            objCollection = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            foreach (var item in context.Request.Headers)
            {
                objCollection.Add(item.Key, string.Join(string.Empty, item.Value));
            }
        }

        public bool ContainsPrefix(string prefix)
        {
            return objCollection.Keys.Contains(prefix);
        }

        public ValueProviderResult GetValue(string key)
        {
            if (key == null)
                throw new Exception("NullReferenceException");

            if (objCollection.TryGetValue(key, out string resultValue))
            {
                return new ValueProviderResult(resultValue, resultValue, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }


            return null;
        }

    }
```

I want to change the signature of the API method, so that i can access the full request header object inside the body of the API method. It would be great, if i can access the full objCollection inside the API method.  Because i would to use other header values as well inside the method.

Please suggest how to make this code change.

Comment: I'd wouldn't use a valueprovider, but an actionfilter.  In the actionfilter you can set the tempdata for the action and access it in the controller method.

Comment: @Fran , please provide any sample if you have.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25197372/187365

Comment: My case is of webAPI, but the sample shared is of MVC. There is a difference. I am not able to use the tempData in webAPI.

Comment: Try using the Request.Properties[] of the action filter context

Comment: I resolved it. You can post your answer and i will accept the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom attribute and set a key in Request.Properties[].  You will be able to access that from your controller action

```
public class MyNewAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        actionContext.Request.Properties[<yourkey] = <your value>;
    }
}
```

However, why do you need this information in your controller action?  If it's information you need in your request, why not include it in the payload of the call instead of the header?

Comment: public Dictionary<string, string> headerCollection;

        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);

            headerCollection = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            foreach (var item in actionContext.Request.Headers)
            {
                headerCollection.Add(item.Key, string.Join(string.Empty, item.Value));
            }

            actionContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values.Add("RequestHeaderCollection", headerCollection);
            
        }

Comment: actionContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values.Add("RequestHeaderCollection", headerCollection);

Comment: RequestContext is more suitable.

Comment: For every API call, i would like to fetch and prepare the collection with its new incoming header information.